# pandas dataframe convert columns as rows

Tags: python, pandas

I am looking for a way to convert my dataframe columns as rows. Following is my example dataframe:

```
mylist= [['xx'], [None, 'yy'], ['xx', None], ['xx',None],['xx','yy']]

pd.DataFrame(mylist,index=['A','B','C','D','E'],columns=['Col1','Col2'])
```

Input DataFrame:

```
-------------------
Ind | Col1 | Col2 |
-------------------
A   | xx   | None |
B   | None | yy   |
C   | xx   | None |
D   | xx   | None |
E   | xx   | yy   |
-------------------
```

I want to split my columns as separate rows in the dataframe. Below is how my desired output looks like. Can anyone suggest how to acheive the following.

Desired dataframe:

```
------------------------
Ind | Values | Columns |
------------------------
A   | xx     | Col1    |
B   | yy     | Col2    |
C   | xx     | Col1    |
D   | xx     | Col1    |
E   | xx     | Col1    |
E   | xx     | Col2    |
------------------------
```

Thanks,
Rtut

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another option is to use `melt`:

```
longDf = pd.melt(df.reset_index(), id_vars=['index'], var_name=['Columns'])
longDf[pd.notnull(longDf.value)]

  index Columns value
0   A   Col1    xx
2   C   Col1    xx
3   D   Col1    xx
4   E   Col1    xx
6   B   Col2    yy
9   E   Col2    yy
```

Comment: @bernie Thanks. `stack()` is also a great way to do it.

Answer (score 2):

```
df = pd.DataFrame(mylist,index=['A','B','C','D','E'],columns=['Col1','Col2'])
# rotate df
stacked_df = pd.DataFrame(df.stack().reset_index())
# name columns
stacked_df.columns = ['Ind','Columns','Values']
# reorder columns
reordered_df = pd.DataFrame(stacked_df,columns=['Ind','Values','Columns'])
```

Results in:

```
>>> reordered_df
  Ind Values Columns
0   A     xx    Col1
1   B     yy    Col2
2   C     xx    Col1
3   D     xx    Col1
4   E     xx    Col1
5   E     yy    Col2
```

Answer (score 1):

In the case of two values, it appears that you only want the first (e.g. the last row of your example).

You can use `loc` to first set the second value to None in the case both columns have values.

```
df.loc[(df.Col1.notnull()) & (df.Col2.notnull()), 'Col2'] = None
```

You can then [melt](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.melt.html) your results.

```
>>> pd.melt(df.reset_index(), id_vars='index', var_name='Columns', value_name='Values'
            ).dropna().set_index('index')[['Values', 'Columns']]

      Values Columns
index               
A         xx    Col1
C         xx    Col1
D         xx    Col1
E         xx    Col1
B         yy    Col2
```